# Why was the network graph deprecated on GitHub?

Tags: github

On the 1st May 2019, GitHub posted on their blog that they were removing the network graph from the insights panel and that users will be redirected to the forks page. I felt this was a useful tool for visualising branches, so how come it was suddenly removed?

https://github.blog/changelog/2019-05-01-deprecating-the-network-graph/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't GitHub support

Comment: The post you are linked to... was suddenly removed as well.

Comment: and the network graph seems to be back...